# How to check if a string start with a palindrome?

Tags: c++, algorithm, palindrome

I want to check if a string starts with a palindromic substring; I'm looking for the longest palindromic substring which starts with the start of my array.
This is a trivial approach in `O(n*n)`. Is there a smarter way?

```
//not safe for empty string
bool isPalindrome(string s)
{
    string rev = s;
    std::reverse(rev.begin(), rev.end());
    return rev == s;
}

int startWithPalindome(const string a)
{
    int N = a.length();
    for (int len = N; len > 0; len--)
    {
        bool isPal = isPalindrome(a.substr(0,len));
        if (isPal)
            return len;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

EDIT: clarification:  I know this code can be improved in many way, doing variout tweaks, however I'm interested at reducing asymptotic time complexity.

Comment: In isPalindrome, you don't need to reverse the whole string. You know if you have a palindrome at the half-way mark

Comment: All strings trivially start with a zero-length palindrome, so the `return -1;` at the end doesn't seem right.

Comment: I'd say you have a length 1 palindrome by OP's rules as well. You will have the same time complexity but will likely have better average performance if you start at length 2 and go forward.

Comment: @user4581301 - Since he needs the **longest** palindrome, then he needs to start at the end and work backwards. However it's true - at least 1 char palindrome is always there. Unless the string is empty - then 0 chars.

Comment: You would only need to invoke isPalindrome if a.substr(len-1,1) == a.substr(0,1).

Comment: Well, 2 optimizations that I can see here: (1) - the reversing makes a copy of the string in memory. Don't do that. Just compare characters of the same buffer. (2) - You only need to compare if the start is the same as the end, and you can break as soon as you find a discrepancy or reach the middle. Neither of these two things will change the O(n*n), I think, but in practice it will make a big difference.

Comment: Ahhhh, You have me there, @Vilx- .ABB not being a palindrome does not eliminate ABBA. Bad thinking on my part. Backwards it must be.

Comment: The substring will be harming performance as well. You could pass in a reference to the string and the length to scan.

Comment: Manacher's algorithm for this is O(n)

Comment: @Vilx thanks for the hint; I didn't inserted this tweaking to concentrate in asymptotic cost. However your answer is appreciated

Comment: Poor Asians, Russians, Africans, people from most European countries, never getting thought of by the writers of palindrome-checking functions. Very naïve.

Comment: Have you consider using a suffix tree?

Answer (score 0):

**Optimize startWithPalindrome()**

Your approach is to look for the largest possible palindrome, and use brute force to reduce successively the size of the substring that you consider, until you find a palindrome.

You could easily prune lots of comparisons, by starting not with the total size of the string but looking for the last occurence of the first char using [`rfind()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind).  THen you could iterate backwards to the previous position of that char and so on:

```
int startWithPalindome(const string a)
{
    if (a.length()>1)
    {
        for (int N = a.rfind(a[0]); N!=string::npos && N>0; N= a.rfind(a[0],N-1) ) {
            if ( isPalindrome(a.substr(0,N+1)) )
                return N+1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

**By the way: Optimisation of isPalindrome()**

Your version of `isPalindrom()` considers an empty string or a single character string as a palindrome.  You could keep it so, but I'd suggest to eliminate such cases.

I propose you nevertheless a small variant, that doesn't copy the string, but just iterates through it from the beginning and the end, hence doing (almost) the smallest number of operations:

```
bool isPalindrome(string s)
{
    if (s.length()<2)       // empty strings and singles chars are no palindromes !
        return false;   
    for (auto f=s.cbegin(), r=s.cend()-1; f!=r;  r--) {
        if (*f!=*r)         // if the nth letter from start doesn't match nth from ens
            return false;        // not a palindrom
        if (++f==r)         // if middle of string is between two chars
            break;     
    }
    return true;            // we meet in the middle so it's a palindrome 
}
```

[**Online demo**](http://ideone.com/fBkZ7n)

Comment: Thank this is useful. However I still hope to find looking for a more efficient solution in `O(n)` time